# SpringREST How to validate Date passed in request body No validator could be found for constraint 'com.event.validator.IsValidDate

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-data-jpa

The EventDomainobject has a Date object inside it.
I need to validate the Date object.

If the JSON that is posted in the request has an invalid date format, then I would like to handle that situation.

```
@PostMapping("/customer/save")
    public ResponseEntity<EventDto> bookSlotEvent(@Valid @RequestBody EventDomain eventDomain) {

        EventDto eventDto=eventService.save(eventDomain);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(eventDto);
    }
```

*

Actually, I am validating dd-mm-yyyy format but I am getting no validator could be found for constraint

```
    //properties class
        @IsValidDate
        private Date startDate;
```

Interface:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy=DateConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsValidDate {
    String message() default "invalid date format";
    Class<?>[] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I'm validating in data format dd-mm-yyyy but I am getting HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint validating type 'java.util.Date'

```
    public class DateConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IsValidDate, String>{

        @Override
        public void initialize(IsValidDate isValidDate) {
            isValidDate.message();
        }
       @Override
        public boolean isValid(String indate, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");

            simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
            try {
                simpleDateFormat.parse(indate.trim());`


            } catch (ParseException  e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I'm sure we would be willing to help.

Comment: bro this example is reproducible ...how to validate date format